# Сделать выборку с подсчетом количества для каждого типа

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

День добрый, только изучаю SQL не могу разобраться, задача такая:
По каждому типу взыскания получить общее количество наложенных взысканий для
всех типов должностей

есть бд со следующими таблицами и полями

Личная карточка

- личный номер
- код должности
- наименование должности

послужной список

- личный номер
- дата поощрения
- вид поощрения
- дата взыскания
- вид взыскания
  подсчитать количество по отдельности разобрался

  ```
  SELECT "Послужной список"."Вид взыскания",
         COUNT ("Послужной список"."Вид взыскания")
  FROM public."Личная карточка",
       public."Послужной список"
  GROUP BY "Послужной список"."Вид взыскания"
  ```

а все вместе пока не пойму как

Comment: А что не так? у тебя сейчас как раз и получается вид взыскания и количество взысканий этого типа, без деления на должности или ещё как.

Comment: да вот именно, с этим все в порядке, разобрался,
мне же в итоге нужно получить с делением по должностям

Comment: Добавьте ещё одно поле  - в выходной набор и в выражение группировки.

Comment: О, да точно))) работает))) спасибо большое)